# Rename all keys inside of a specific dictionary in fluentd

Tags: fluentd

Does anyone have any idea how I can filter the elements of a specific list of dictionaries to add a prepended name to the keys of all elements? The field name that is the list of dictionaries is static and known ahead of time.  However, the elements inside each dictionary are not.  I have tried to use fluent-plugin-rewrite and fluent-plugin-record-transformer without success.

I have a record like the following.  I know 'g' ahead of time, but the fact there are two entries in the dictionary and that the specific elements are 'h, i, k, and l' are dynamic.

```
{
    "a": "d1",
    "b": "d2",
    "c": {
           "e": "d3",
           "f": "d4"
         },
    "g": [
            {
             "h": "d5",
             "i": "d6",         
            },
            {
             "h": "d7",
             "k": "d8", 
             "l": "d9", 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

That I would like to change to:

```
{
    "a": "d1",
    "b": "d2",
    "c": {
           "e": "d3",
           "f": "d4"
         },
    "g": [
            {
             "prepend_h": "d5",
             "prepend_i": "d6",         
            },
            {
             "prepend_h": "d7",
             "prepend_k": "d8", 
             "prepend_l": "d9", 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```